# Download button in table conflict with Carousel

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a table with some data in it and have one cell containing a button which downloads a pdf file.

```
<td>
    <a  download  target="_blank" href="Bilder/GrundrissA1.pdf"  title="Grundriss A1" >
        <span class="fa fa-file-o"></span>                                     
    </a>
</td>
```

The problem is that it won't open, unless I **right click** and "open in new tab". The reason lies with in the table, since if I just use the following code outside of a table it works fine

```
 <a  download  target="_blank" href="Bilder/GrundrissA1.pdf"  title="Grundriss A1" >
     <span class="fa fa-file-o"></span>                                     
 </a>
```

After removing some content to see what causes the issue I found that the carousel I linked to the table is interfering with the **left-clicking**

```
<tr onclick="" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0">
```

removing `data-target="#carousel"` or `data-slide-to="0"` both solves the issue. But I really need this to control the Carousel

The question is, how do I make the download button work properly while being able to control the carousel by clicking the tablerows?

This would be a simplified (without Navbar,fewer tablerows, footer etc) version of the webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 align-self-center " style="padding-top:5%;padding-bottom:5%;">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-bordered">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Wohnung</th>
                    <th>Etage</th>
                    <th>Zimmer</th>
                    <th>Wohnfläche</th>
                    <th>Balkon/Sitzplatz</th>
                    <th>Keller</th>
                    <th>Kaufpreis</th>
                    <th>Grundriss</th>

                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr onclick="" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0">
                    <td>A1</td>
                    <td>EG</td>
                    <td>3,5</td>
                    <td>84,5 m²</td>
                    <td>16,2 m²</td>
                    <td>8 m²</td>
                    <td> CHF 630'000</td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" title="Grundriss A1" target="_blank">
                        <span class="fa fa-file-o"></span>                                  
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>

      <!--Carousel-->
          <div class="col-md-12  col-lg-4">
            <div id="carousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" style="margin-top:5%">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600" alt="A1">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600" alt="A1">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600" alt="A2">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--carousel End-->



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why putting a link in a table would keep it from opening in a new window.  Do you have any sort of javascript logic associated with this table in regards to click handlers?

Comment: I do not, I am just using the normal bootstrap jscript. I'm a bloody beginner, and have no experience with Jscript/Jquery and thus didnt customize it at all.

Comment: You need to add download attribute

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Taplar, I edited it correspondingly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lj3zw5v/  I put your markup into a fiddle (added the ending two closing divs) and added "Download" to the link so I could see it.  When I click that link in the fiddle, it opens a new tab.  So this doesn't seem to replicate your issue.  Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lj3zw5v/2/  changed it to be a dummy pdf file and the window still opens.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lj3zw5v/4/  Added bootstrap, it still opens a new window

Comment: I'll try to find the problem by excluding everything unnecessary and then re-adding the other content until it breaks again. Ill update asap. Thanks a lot Taplar though!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the **download** attr to the `<a></a>`
Something like this:

```
<a download target="_blank" href="/Bilder/GrundrissA2.pdf" title="GrundrissA2">Download</a>
```

Comment: I did do that, but it didn't solve the issue. Like I said in the post, if I put the downloadbutton outside of the table, it works without a problem. As soon as it's in the table the link doesnt work, with 'download' or without.